# Factorización LU en C++

Tags: c++

Muy buen día a todos!

Les comento que [he encontrado un código en internet](http://www.openboxer.260mb.com/ccp/lu.txt?i=1) para solucionar sistemas de ecuaciones lineales en C++ utilizacion la factorización LU pero hay una parte que no entiendo.
Les muestro dicho fragmento (el original):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        sum=0;
        if(i<=j)
        {
            for(k=0;k<n;k++) 
                if(k!=i)
                    sum=sum+l[i][k]*u[k][j];
                    u[i][j]=a[i][j]-sum;
        }
        else 
        {
            for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                if(k!=j)
                    sum=sum+l[i][k]*u[k][j];
                l[i][j]=(a[i][j]-sum)/u[j][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Y ahora les muestro el que yo edité:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            sum=0;
            if(i<=j){               //Es decir, solo se llenan los elementos de la diagonal y encima de ella para U
                for(k=0;k<n;k++){
                    if(k!=i){
                        sum=sum+L[i][k]*U[k][j];
                    }else {
                        U[i][j]=A[i][j]-sum;               //Llenado de elementos restantes de U
                    }
                }
            } else{                 //Es decir, solo se llenan los elementos debajo de la diagonal para L
                for(k=0;k<n;k++){
                    if(k!=j){
                        sum=sum+L[i][k]*U[k][j];
                    }else {
                        L[i][j]=(A[i][j]-sum)/U[j][j];      //Llenado de elementos restantes de L
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Preguntas:

1. Ambos códigos funcionan correctamente pero mi pregunta es, por qué? Ya que el que yo edité tiene un par de 'else' más y no entiendo porque el original corre sin ellos.
2. Allí se usa una variable de iteración k. En el segundo if indica que el código dentro de éste sólo se ejecutará si k es diferente de i. ¿Por qué es esto? Por qué k no puede ser igual a i? Y cómo se llena el elemento en el caso de que i sea igual a k?

Ahora muestro el código completo:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int i=0,j=0,k=0,n=0;

std::cout << "\t\tDESCOMPOSICION LU";
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "El orden de la matriz debe ser mayor o igual que 2 y entero." << std::endl;
std::cout << "Ingresa el orden de la matriz: ";
std::cin >> n;

//Comprobacion de ingreso de un valor correcto para el orden de la matriz
if(n<=1){
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "No ha ingresado un valor correcto. Cerrando el programa...";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
} else {
    float A[n][n]={0}, B[n]={0}, X[n]={0}, L[n][n]={0}, Y[n]={0}, U[n][n]={0},sum=0;
    std::cout << "La matriz es de " << n << "x" << n <<".";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //Obtencion de los elementos de la matriz A de coeficientes
    std::cout<<"Ingrese los coeficientes de la matriz A de coeficientes: ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            std::cout << "Ingrese el elemento A["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"]: ";
            std::cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //Obtencion de los elementos de la matriz B
    std::cout << "Ingrese la matriz B:" << std::endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cout << "Ingrese el elemento B["<<i+1<<"]: ";
        std::cin >> B[i];
    }

    //Descomposicion LU

    //Llenado de ceros y unos en posiciones conocidas
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(i>j){
              U[i][j]=0;    //Ceros debajo de la diagonal para la matriz U
            }
            else if(i==j){
              L[i][j]=1;    //Unos en la diagonal de L
            } else{
              L[i][j]=0;    //Ceros encima de la diagonal para la matriz L
            }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            sum=0;
            if(i<=j){               //Es decir, solo se llenan los elementos de la diagonal y encima de ella para U
                for(k=0;k<n;k++){
                    if(k!=i){
                        sum=sum+L[i][k]*U[k][j];
                    }else {
                        U[i][j]=A[i][j]-sum;               //Llenado de elementos restantes de U
                    }
                }
            } else{                 //Es decir, solo se llenan los elementos debajo de la diagonal para L
                for(k=0;k<n;k++){
                    if(k!=j){
                        sum=sum+L[i][k]*U[k][j];
                    }else {
                        L[i][j]=(A[i][j]-sum)/U[j][j];      //Llenado de elementos restantes de L
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

        printf("\n\n L =");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)

                        printf ("%10.2f",L[i][j]);
            printf("\n    ");
    }

        printf("\n\n U =");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                         printf ("%10.2f",U[i][j]);
            printf("\n    ");
    }

    Y[0]=B[0]/L[0][0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+Y[j]*L[i][j];

        }
        Y[i]=B[i]-sum;
    }
    printf("\n\n Y =");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
                printf ("%10.2f",Y[i]);
            printf("\n    ");
    }

    X[n-1]=Y[n-1]/U[n-1][n-1];
    for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
        sum=0;
        for(j=n-1;j>i;j--)
            sum=sum+X[j]*U[i][j];
        X[i]=(Y[i]-sum)/U[i][i];
    }

    printf("\nLa solucion es :\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\n x[%d] = %.2f ",i+1,X[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

}

Tal vez se estén preguntando por el uso de cout y printf en el mismo código. Sucede que, como ya mencioné, el código lo encontré en internet y lo he ido cambiando a medida que voy entendiendo línea por línea. Como no he comprendido el fragmento en cuestión, aún no he editado las líneas siguientes a éste.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Como había comentado: "Tal vez se estén preguntando por el uso de cout y printf en el mismo código. Sucede que, como ya mencioné, el código lo encontré en internet y lo he ido cambiando a medida que voy entendiendo línea por línea. Como no he comprendido el fragmento en cuestión, aún no he editado las líneas siguientes a éste."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo primero a mencionar es que el código original (el primero que pones) no usa llaves en ciertos bucles ni ifs, pero la indentación llama a engaño. Fíjate por ejemplo en esta parte:

```
        for(k=0;k<n;k++) 
            if(k!=i)
                sum=sum+l[i][k]*u[k][j];
                u[i][j]=a[i][j]-sum;
```

Debido a la indentación, da la impresión de que la línea `u[i][j]` es parte del cuerpo del `if`, pero no es así ya que ho hay llaves que lo delimiten. De hecho, tampoco forma parte del cuerpo del `for`, ya que, al carecer también de llaves, su cuerpo se limita a la línea con el `if`. Por tanto, una forma más correcta de indentarlo sería:

```
        for(k=0;k<n;k++) 
            if(k!=i)
                sum=sum+l[i][k]*u[k][j];
        u[i][j]=a[i][j]-sum;
```

Mejor aún, poner llaves explícitas aún si el cuerpo es una sola línea:

```
        for(k=0;k<n;k++) {
            if(k!=i) {
                sum=sum+l[i][k]*u[k][j];
            }
        }
        u[i][j]=a[i][j]-sum;
```

Por tanto, la misión del bucle `for(k)` es simplemente actualizar la variable `sum` para que, una vez salgas del bucle, la uses para asignar el elemento `u[i][j]`.

Una vez aclarado esto, creo que es más fácil ver el por qué de lo que preguntas:

> 1. Ambos códigos funcionan correctamente pero mi pregunta es, por qué? Ya que el que yo edité tiene un par de 'else' más y no entiendo porque el original corre sin ellos.

Si te fijas, la línea `u[i][j]=a[i][j]-sum;` no usa para nada el índice `k`. Al ser independiente de este índice, si lo metes dentro del bucle `for` simplemente estarías ejecutándola muchas veces (y ya que `i` y `j` son constantes dentro del bucle `for(k)`, simplemente la estarías reescribiendo muchas veces y el único valor que contará será el último escrito).

No obstante, tú lo has metido como parte de un `else`. No veo claro aquí que vaya a salir el mismo resultado ya que en el código original el valor de `u[i][j]` se actualiza con el valor que tiene `sum` una vez se salga del bucle `for(k)`, mientras que en tu caso se actualiza con el valor que tiene `sum` justo para el caso en que `i==k`. A menos que este caso coincida en la última iteración del bucle, en general tu resultado sería diferente.

> 2. Allí se usa una variable de iteración k. En el segundo if indica que el código dentro de éste sólo se ejecutará si k es diferente de i. ¿Por qué es esto? Por qué k no puede ser igual a i?

Este ya es un detalle de esta implementación particular de LU, y no he entrado a comprender en profundidad por qué lo hace así. A la hora de actualizar `sum`, se salta el caso `i==k`, pero no veo claro por qué. [Otras implementaciones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#C#_code_examples) no lo hacen así. Quizás sea una optimización para evitar calcular ese caso porque ya sabe que siempre es cero, pero en todo caso se está perdiendo tiempo en comprobar si `k!=i` en cada iteración del bucle por lo que no me parece una buena optimización.

> Y cómo se llena el elemento en el caso de que i sea igual a k?

Como vimos antes, al indentarlo correctamente, el elemento se rellena igualmente al salir del bucle `for(k)`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Ya entiendo el código a la perfección. Es cierto, no es muy eficiente el estar comprobando si k es igual o no a i.
De veras, muchísimas gracias!